# nginx not starting in alpine docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I got a very basic `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

RUN nginx
```

I even tried

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx" ]
```

but then the container is continuously restarting instead of starting.

But when I start the container (having RUN nginx in place) and I attach a console to the container and run nginx, the process starts.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the CMD command.
`CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

Your Dockerfile would then look like this:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Source:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/nginx-docker-container

Comment: This is working but when I do this, fpm is not starting

Comment: Could you please share the errors you are getting, it would be easier, thx

Comment: What errors do you mean? I am using the image `php:8.1-fpm-alpine` which starts the fpm process, so that I can reverse proxy to port 9000. With your command, the fpm process is not starting. There is no error.

Comment: You can see logs and errors if you type `docker logs --follow container_name`. Can you see any errors there?

Comment: no only thing I see when I don't use the "correct" nginx command, I see the log for fpm starting and with the nginx command I don't see it and it did not start